# Counting several sums on same query fails

Tags: mysql

I run a query, where I count several `sum`s on the different fields of same database entity. My problem arises when I am running tests on the query and at the same time changing the query from Mysql to the native language used on tests in IntelliJ Idea tool (I don't know what it uses).

Problem is this: in the new environment all `sum` statements inside the single query return the value equal to the one that is got of the first `sum` statement.

I am using JPA and NativeQuery.

More information:
I have a code like this

> List < Object [ ] > row = List < Object [ ] > em.createNativeQuery("select sum (e.field), sum (e.otherField) from entity e where somevalue = something").getResultList();

and then

> return new MyResult ( ( Double ) row.get ( 0 ) [ 0 ] , ( Double )row.get ( 0 ) [ 1 ] );

Everything is inside a doInJPA function.

Comment: You're a bit light on the information. How about example DDL, data and query that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I added some extra information.

Comment: This really belongs in StackOverflow as this question has to do with Java Persistence Query Language which is probably a SQL dialect that is not properly MySQL aware. Someone with Java experience can better address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real issue was identified to be so that my Idea used for testing HSQL and that somehow does not support `sum` in the same way that Mysql does.